# Digital Logic Design - Sequential Circuits

Tags: sequential-logic

The circuit diagram below is in a stable state because of the two inverters. Why and how did it reach a stable state?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you accept that a logic level can be only 0 and 1 it is clear that the circuit *must* be in one of the two states, because there are no other (stable) states for it to be in.

If you relax this assumption there can be, depending on the transfer characteristic of the inverters, more stable states, for instance all nodes at 1/2.

In practice, an inverter will likely amplify, and that 1/2 state will be amplified towards one of the two stable states. (In theory it could still be at 1/2 forever, this is called a meta-stable state, and it is a real problem in some circumstances.)

How did the circuit arrive at one of the two states? If the inverters amplify, all states above 1/2 will quickly be amplified to 1, and below 1/2 to 0.

In practice there will be more circuitry around your 'memory cell', which can force the cell to one of the states.

Comment: I agree but I think you buried the lede...the last sentence is probably what the OP needed to hear.

Comment: He asked two questions, so I addresses the why first. The last sentence assumes something about the question, which might be true or not.